# How to test a clustered Express app with Mocha?

Tags: node.js, express

Here is a simplified version of my cluster Express app:

**/index.js**

```
module.exports = process.env.CODE_COV
    ? require('./lib-cov/app')
    : require('./lib/app');
```

**/lib/app.js**

```
var cluster = require('cluster'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports = express.createServer();

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Considering I have 4 cores.
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    // do app configurations, then...

    // Don't listen to this port if the app is required from a test script.
    if (!module.parent.parent) {
        app.listen(8080);
    }
}
```

**/test/test1.js**

```
var app = require('../');

app.listen(7777);

// send requests to app, then assert the response.
```

**Questions:**

1. `var app = require('../');` will not work in this cluster environment. Which of the worker apps should it return? Should it return the cluster object instead of an Express app?
2. Now, obviously setting the port in the test script will not work. How would you set a port within a test script to a cluster of apps?
3. How would you send requests to this cluster of apps?

The only solution I can think of is to conditionally turn off the clustering feature and run only one app if the app is requested from a test script (`if (module.parent.parent) ...`).

Any other way to test a clustered Express app with Mocha?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's been quite a long time since I have posted this question. Since no one has answered, I will answer to this question myself.

I kept the **/index.js** as it is:

```
module.exports = process.env.CODE_COV
    ? require('./lib-cov/app')
    : require('./lib/app');
```

In **/lib/app.js** which starts the cluster, I have the following code. In brief, I start the cluster only in non-test environment. In test environment the cluster is not started but only one app/worker itself is started as defined in the `cluster.isMaster && !module.parent.parent` condition.

```
var cluster = require('cluster'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports = express.createServer();

if (cluster.isMaster && !module.parent.parent) {
    // Considering I have 4 cores.
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    // do app configurations, then...

    // Don't listen to this port if the app is required from a test script.
    if (!module.parent.parent) {
        app.listen(8080);
    }
}
```

In the above case `!module.parent.parent` will be evaluated as a truthful object only if the application was not started by a test script.

1. `module` is the current **/lib/app.js** script.
2. `module.parent` is its parent **/index.js** script.
3. `module.parent.parent` is `undefined` if the application was started directly via `node index.js`.
4. `module.parent.parent` is the test script if the application was started via one of the scripts.

Thus, I can safely start the script where I can set a custom port.

**/test/test1.js**

```
var app = require('../');

app.listen(7777);

// send requests to app, then assert the response.
```

At the same time if I need to run the application in real, i.e. not for testing, then I run `node index.js` and it will start up the cluster of applications.

Answer (score 2):

I have a much simpler way of doing this

```
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
        var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
        console.log('total cpu cores on this host: ', numCPUs);
        for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
            console.log('forking worker...');
            cluster.fork();
        }

        cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
            console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online.');
        });
        cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
            console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died.');
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Im a worker');
        // application code 
        setupServer()
    }
} else {
    // when running tests
    setupServer();
    }
```

Just make sure to set the env to `test` when running the tests
ex: `NODE_ENV=test grunt test`

Answer (score 0):

I kind of liked your solution because of it's simplicity, however, in an environment like an MVC framework for node, you may end up chaining module.parent up to 11 times (seriously).

I think a better approach would be to simply check which script node started processing with. The node's command-line arguments are available at process.argv.
The first item in this array would be 'node', the executable and the second argument would be the path to the file that node start executing. This would be index.js in your case.

So instead of checking

```
                   module.parent.parent
                            ^       ^        
                         (app.js)   |
                                (index.js)
```

You could do something like this

```
var starter = process.argv[1].split(path.sep).pop();
```

Where `starter` would be `index` or `index.js` depending on what you started your server with.
`node index.js` vs `node index`

The check would then look like:

```
if (cluster.isMaster && starter === 'index.js') {
    cluster.fork();
}
```

Worked in my environments—I hope this helps!

Comment: This kind of assumption looks dangerous because I don't know how the arguments list will behave if, for instance, the app is executed throughout forever or pm2 like daemons.

Comment: You do know how the arguments list will behave. 
[process.argv](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) will always contain 0: "node", and 1: the script that node is processing.

Comment: I think you're confusing a cpu thread with a node child process. If you use a daemon monitor
such as forever, forever will start the appropriate master process, which will then delegate 
different forks to running your app. If a forever fork starts up your app, it's still running
`node app.js` at the heart. Which would start up a node process with `process.argv` as ['node', 'path/to/app.js'].

If you use mocha and write a test unit to do something like `exec('node app.js')`, the process.argv will 
still be `['node', 'path/to/app.js']`.

Comment: You're checking the entry point that node was given. In my situation, the node entry point is `sails.js`,
not `index.js`. So if you're saying it's dangerous because the name of your file is `index.js`, then perhaps you
can use more of the path to identify the entry point. This is certainly a better solution 
than identifying whether or not the current file was an exact `n` child in a require tree.