# Testing Cluster in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I'm currently using Mocha for testing but I seem to be running into some errors testing an app that uses Cluster.

Basically, the app exits, but then some of the workers still do things, and this causes weird output which is basically failing the "before all" hooks, even after the tests finished.

I saw this thread [How to test a clustered Express app with Mocha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737448/how-to-test-a-clustered-express-app-with-mocha)

but I wonder if Mocha is even the right module to test a Cluster app with. If so, can someone please point me to a tutorial on how to do it? I couldn't find any after Googling.

I am also using Express in case that complicates things.